# google android market search result

Tags: android, google-play

I submitted my first app to the android market about 3 months ago. Since then I've been getting on average about 10 to 20 downloads a day.
A couple of weeks ago Google released their new market new look and since then my app hasn't been downloaded not even once and I didn't even know why until a few days ago I made search for it using the app title and even though the Android market said that there was over 400 returns for that keyword it only showed about 20 of them and my app wasn't even there.
Does anyone have any information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling, it might have autocorrected your application name.